# could not find /proc/self/maps

Tags: freebsd, procfs

I'm using FreeBSD 7.3 (64 bit). When I try the command "*cat /proc/self/maps*",  I get an error as, "*cat: /proc/self/maps: No such file or directory*". What should I do to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, procfs isn't mounted by default in FreeBSD, so you should do it by yourself. Type as root:

```
mount -t procfs proc /proc
```

Or even better: add to /etc/fstab:

```
proc /proc procfs rw 0 0
```

Comment: I get an error: **mount: unknown filesystem type 'procfs'**